# Why when i set the filtered array from localStorage to state it's return the empty array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the cards on the page from get request and pagination for this cards. I need to close this cards when i click on the close button and i need that this buttons will close automaticly when i update the page. I decieded to use localStorage to solve this problem, but when i filtered the array from localStorage and set it to state state return the empty array. How can i solve this problem?

The component

```
import React, {useEffect, } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import s from './Card.module.css'
import Preloader from "../../Preloader/Preloader";
import Pagination from "../../Pagination/Pagination";

let Cards = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.toggleIsFetching(true)
        axios.get('http://contest.elecard.ru/frontend_data/catalog.json').then((responce) => {
                if(!localStorage.getItem('savedData')) {

                localStorage.setItem('savedData', JSON.stringify(responce.data))
                    props.setCards(responce.data)
            }
            props.toggleIsFetching(false);
        });
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        props.setCards(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData')).filter(e => e.category === props.filterCategory))
    },[props.filterCategory])
    useEffect(() => {
        props.setCards(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData')).filter(e => e.category === props.filterCategory));
    },[localStorage.getItem('savedData')])



    









    const lastCardIndex = props.currentPage * props.cardsPerPage;
    const firstCardIndex = lastCardIndex - props.cardsPerPage;
    const paginate = pageNumber => props.setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

    return (


        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.toggleIsFetching(true)
                axios.get('http://contest.elecard.ru/frontend_data/catalog.json').then((responce) => {
                    props.toggleIsFetching(false);
                    localStorage.setItem('savedData',JSON.stringify(responce.data));

                });
            }}>Remove
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.categoryFilter('');
                props.setTotalCount(660);
            }}>All
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.categoryFilter('animals');
                props.setTotalCount(100);
            }}>Animals
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.categoryFilter('business');
                props.setTotalCount(80);
            }}>Business
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.sortCards('min')
            }}>Filesize min
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.sortCards('max')
            }}>Filesize max
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.sortCards("")
            }}>Filesize Default
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.sortDate('min')
            }}>
                Date min
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                props.sortDate('max')
            }}>
                Date max
            </button>

            <div className={'cardContainer'}>

                {props.isFetching ? <Preloader/> : props.cards
                    .sort((a, b) => props.sortedDate === '' ? null : props.sortedDate === "min" ? a.timestamp - b.timestamp : b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
                    .sort((a, b) => props.sort === '' ? null : props.sort === 'min' ? a.filesize - b.filesize : b.filesize - a.filesize)
                    .slice(firstCardIndex, lastCardIndex)
                    .map(c => <div key={c.filesize} className={'cardWrapper'}>
                        <img onClick={() => {
                            console.log(c.filesize);
                            console.log(c.timestamp)
                        }}  className={s.image} src={`http://contest.elecard.ru/frontend_data/${c.image}`}
                             alt=""/>
                        <div className={s.text}>
                            {c.category}
                        </div>
                        <div className={'date'}>
                            {new Date(c.timestamp).toLocaleString()}
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={(e) => {
                          props.setLocalStorage(c.filesize);
                          props.setTotalCount(props.totalCount - 1);
                        }} className={s.closeBtn}>×
                        </button>
                    </div>)}


            </div>
            <Pagination paginate={paginate} setCurrentPage={props.setCurrentPage} currentPage={props.currentPage}
                        cardsPerPage={props.cardsPerPage}
                        totalCount={props.cards.length}/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Cards;
```

The Reducer

```
let initialState = {
    cards: [

    ],
    isClosed: false,
    filterCategory: "",
    sort: '',
    sortedDate: "",
    isFetching: true,
    currentPage: 1,
    cardsPerPage: 9,
    totalCount: 660,
    array: [

    ],

}

const cardsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case SET_CARDS:
        return {...state, cards:[...action.cards]};
    case SET_IS_CLOSED:
        return {
            ...state, cards: state.cards.map(u => {
                if(u.filesize === action.id) {
                    return {...u, closed: '123',}
                }
                return u
            })};
    case SET_LOCAL_STORAGE:
     let savedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData'));
     savedData.map((card,index) => {
         if(card.filesize === action.id) {
             savedData.splice(index,1);
         }
     })
        localStorage.setItem('savedData',JSON.stringify(savedData));


    case CATEGORY_FILTER:
        localStorage.setItem('category',action.category)
        return {
            ...state, filterCategory: action.category,
        }

    case SORT_CARDS:
        return {
            ...state, sort: action.val
        }
    case SORT_DATE:
        return {
            ...state, sortedDate: action.val
        }
    case TOGGLE_IS_FETCHING:
        return {
            ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching
        }
    case SET_CURRENT_PAGE:
        return {
            ...state, currentPage: action.page
        }
    case SET_TOTAL_COUNT:
        return {
            ...state, totalCount: action.count,
        }



    default:
        return state;
}
};


let SET_TOTAL_COUNT = "SET_TOTAL_COUNT";
let SET_CURRENT_PAGE = "SET_CURRENT_PAGE";
let TOGGLE_IS_FETCHING = "TOGGLE_IS_FETCHING";
let SORT_DATE = "SORT_DATE";
let SORT_CARDS = "SORT_CARDS";
let CATEGORY_FILTER = "CATEGORY_FILTER";
let SET_LOCAL_STORAGE = "SET_LOCAL_STORAGE";
let SET_CARDS = "SET_CARDS";
let SET_IS_CLOSED = "SET_IS_CLOSED";
export let setTotalCountAC = (count) => ({type: SET_TOTAL_COUNT, count});
export let setCurrentPageAC = (page) => ({type: SET_CURRENT_PAGE, page});
export let toggleIsFetchingAC = (isFetching) => ({type: TOGGLE_IS_FETCHING,isFetching});
export let sortDateAC = (val) => ({type: SORT_DATE, val});
export let sortCardsAC = (val) => ({type: SORT_CARDS, val});
export let categoryFilterAC = (category) => ({type: CATEGORY_FILTER, category});
export let setIsClosedAC = (id) => ({type: SET_IS_CLOSED, id});
export let setCardsAC = (cards) => ({type: SET_CARDS,cards});
export let setLocalStorageAC = (id) => ({type: SET_LOCAL_STORAGE, id});
export default cardsReducer;
```

I need to set a filtered array to state from localStorage when localStorage is chaning